# ¿Como puedo conseguir el mismo resultado, pero ingresando los valores por teclado?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 int primerNumero;
 int segundoNumero;
 int tercerNumero;
/*Cuando intento ingresar por ejemplo el valor del primer numero por teclado con scanf, luego me tira error si intento--> segundoNumero = 0primerNumero;*/
/*Quiero lograr hacer la conversión de la misma forma*/

/*ESTO ES LO QUE QUIERO INTENTAR CONSEGUIR
scanf("%d",&primerNumero);
segundoNumero = 0primerNumero;
tercerNumero = 0xprimerNumero;*/
 primerNumero = 15;
 segundoNumero = 015;
 tercerNumero = 0x15;
 printf("El primer numero es %d, ", primerNumero);
 printf("el segundo es %d, ", segundoNumero);
 printf("el tercer numero es %d.", tercerNumero);
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
El primer numero es 15, el segundo es 13, el tercer numero es 21.
```

Comment: Los nombres variables no pueden empezar con un número `0primerNumero` y `0xprimerNumero` no son nombres válidos. Los literales numéricos que empiezan con cero (`0`) son valores octales, `015` es 13 en decimal. Los literales que empiezan con `0x` son valores hexadecimales, `0x15` es 21 en decimal... ¿cuál es tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es, primeramente, leer el dato como una cadena. ¿Por qué? Porque una vez que lo tienes en formato numérico la base se pierde (el ordenador internamente trabaja con una base fija).

Una vez has leído el número como una cadena lo que puedes hacer es usar una función similar a `scanf` para interpretar el número con diferentes bases:

```
#include <string.h>

char buffer[10];
scanf("%s",buffer);

sscanf(buffer,"%d",&primerNumero);  // %d -> base 10
sscanf(buffer,"%o",&segundoNumero); // %o -> base 8
sscanf(buffer,"%x",&tercerNumero);  // %x -> base 16
```

`sscanf` funciona igual a `scanf` solo que en vez de recuperar los datos de `stdin` procesa el buffer que se le pasa como primer parámetro.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias! si resulta y ademas de una forma simple y sencilla!

Comment: eferion, yo hice esta pregunta porque estaba trabajando en un conversor de numeros como este: https://coderstoolbox.net/number/

Me surgio la duda si en en C puede ser posible un funcionamiento similar.. Si te fijas en el conversor del enlace, el buffer se refresca a medida que se ingresan datos y sin necesidad de presionar el ENTER.

Comment: @JonathanYañez puedes leer carácter a carácter con `getchar()` e ir concatenando los caracteres en el buffer... en cada iteración ejecutas las conversiones y listo. Si quieres algo mas sofisticado tendrás que usar librerías de terceros ya que el estándar no da más de sí